# Will Continuous flying damage the aircraft?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I am now having a test on various flying vehicles with continuous flying. Now I tried:

- Frogger
- Maverick
- Titan

Engines of all the above will produce smoke trail after a in-game day of flying (given that Titan has retracted the landing gear during take off). Then continue to fly for half day, the plane will drop altitude significantly (though full throttle is set, and the plane is leveled). Flying for 2 days, I am forced to land the plane on an airstrip.

Does this prove that continuous flying will damage the aircraft?

p.s. I was just dodging the bounty :P

Comment: It would seem logical that you'll run out of fuel. Just thinking there.